# Cookie-less authentication with session ID

Tags: 8, sessions

I'm building [decoupled drupal site](http://buytaert.net/how-should-you-decouple-drupal). I need to be able to authenticate REST client via session ID passed in a URL (or maybe custom header) instead of a cookie.

At first I thought about implementing my own `AuthenticationProviderInterface` that would work pretty much the same as `Drupal\user\Authentication\Provider\Cookie` does, but when I looked into the `Cookie` class itself I thought that I should rather play with session object and "teach" it how to read session id from alternative source instead of reading it from a cookie.

How can I do that?

Should I swap `session_configuration` (which directly accesses `Request::cookies`) or maybe `session` service? Do I need to swap them at all?

The crucial part is that I don't want to loose standard cookie authentication. I just want to be able to authenticate with session ID when there is no session cookie.

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use cookies, it might help to give you an answer.

Comment: Interesting question. I found https://gist.github.com/manjeshpv/79d0540a97427796cc52 using PHPSESSID transforming it into $_COOKIE .. can the web server do this instead of Drupal?

Comment: @longboardnode this is for a REST service. Using cookies with REST calls is really not very convenient.

Comment: @ClemensTolboom interesting hack, though it would require me to plug into request stack before session service. And it's a bit awkward because session service provides session cookie name. Circular dependency unless I'll reproduce session service code to get cookie name. This starts to sound really bad.

Comment: @SiliconMind is your REST Client on a single IP so you can auth against the IP address and perhaps some token with each request?

Comment: @longboardnode I can't rely on IP auth as some clients might not have fixed IP.

Comment: @SiliconMind I just had to set up a services api with another system. This was a bit different than your scenario and on D7 so FWIW, I ended up modifying the [Services API Key](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_api_key_auth)  to hash and a rotational salt the key using the PHP HMAC+SHA1 function. The other system hashed the key and sent it over with each request, and Drupal compared it to the hash on Drupal side and allowed/disallowed accordingly. Not sure if it'd help you...

Comment: @longboardnode API key could probably work in some scenarios. The services api kay module is for D7 only. Do you know of any resources that apply to D8?

Comment: @SiliconMind sorry I'm not familiar with D8 services, which AFAIK is part of core now. I can only suggest to look at what auth hooks you can add to the rest service and then code your API key there... hope that helps...

Comment: I use oauth2 server module and is Great for authentication on rest services.